# Serial connection two devices two power supplies

Tags: serial, esp32

I'm trying to connect an ESP32-CAM to a 3d printer using a serial connection.
When powering the ESP from the 5V rail on the 3D printer(and using 3.3V zener diodes between tx, rx & gnd), everything works fine. The ESP expects 3.3V on the serial pins, hence the diodes.

[image]

[circuit diagram](https://i.ibb.co/QFJXBQG/Ender3-relay-pptx-Microsoft-Power-Point-000291.jpg)

Common ground not shown.

Then when I try to run the ESP32 from its own 5v power supply, I cannot establish a serial connection, regardless of whether I connect the gnd from the 5v from the 3d printer with that of the ESP power supply.
In fact, the ESP doesn't function then.

Any suggestions?

PS: the ESP has its own power since it should trigger a relay to cut power to the printer.

Comment: use a logic level converter

Answer (score 1):

The 3.3V zener diodes are connected backwards. The anode should be connected to ground and the cathode (banded end) to the GPIO signal. Zener diodes work in reverse bias...as you have them connected now they are forward biased and will clamp the signals to about 0.7V.

The zener diode on the line for data transmitted at 3.3V to a 5V input doesn't do any good. You need to **increase** that signal voltage to a proper 5V logic level. The best thing to do would be to get rid of the zener diodes altogether and use a proper logic level converter.

Also, you really should have resistors between GPIO output pins and the zener diodes, to limit the current through the zeners when the GPIO pin is at 5V.